# mapDispatchToProps is not making my ActionCreator a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {getAgeOptions, getGenderOptions} from '../actions/options-actions';
import ItemTextEdit from '../components/ItemTextEdit';
import DropSelect from '../containers/DropSelect';

export class BookDetail extends Component{
    render(){
        if(!this.props.book){
            return <div>Select a book to get started.</div>;
        }

console.log(this.props.getGenderOptions());
        return(
           <div>
...other code was here to display
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({getAgeOptions:getAgeOptions, getGenderOptions:getGenderOptions}, dispatch);

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        book: state.activeBook
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookDetail);
```

When I run this code with "console.log(this.props.getGenderOptions);" it console logs out a f(){} but when I try to call it above it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: this.props.getGenderOptions is not a function
>   Here is the action creator:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const ROOT_URL = `http://localhost:8080/`;
const ROOT_OPTIONS_URL = `${ROOT_URL}options`;

export const GET_GENDER_OPTIONS = 'GET_GENDER_OPTIONS';
export const GET_AGE_OPTIONS = 'GET_AGE_OPTIONS';

export function getGenderOptions() {
    const url = `${ROOT_OPTIONS_URL}/gender`;
    const request = axios.get(url);
    return {
        type: GET_GENDER_OPTIONS,
        payload: request

    }
}

export function getAgeOptions() {
    const url = `${ROOT_OPTIONS_URL}/age`;
    const request = axios.get(url);
    return {
        type: GET_AGE_OPTIONS,
        payload: request

    }
}
```

I am not sure why I am not getting my function back.

Comment: Are you missing an import for `bindActionCreators`?  should be `import { bindActionCreators } from 'react-redux'`

Comment: nope, just didn't add that into the paste. Fixed above now.

Comment: it appears to be console logging a promise. Which is odd because my promise in axios never gets passed to the return. I am passing the request in the payload. In other parts of my code this convention works.

Comment: I don't see where you call `this.props.getGenderOptions()` since it's an action that fires a request I'd expect to see it in your react lifecycle or as an `onClick` event

Comment: I am calling it in the console.log in the render function. I am just trying to get it to respond and it keeps saying it is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing an axios request you should await it, `axios.get()` returns a promise so in your case you'll have to (same for the other function):

```
export async function getAgeOptions() {
  const url = `${ROOT_OPTIONS_URL}/age`;
  const request = await axios.get(url);
  return {
    type: GET_AGE_OPTIONS,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

This will `resolve` or `reject` your promise giving you the desired output. You can find more about this subject on: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Also using the `connect()` from `react-redux` greatly improves code readability, it's a High-Order-Component that will wrap your component with `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: I think my problem is more of a fact I am getting the promise and not getting a function back when I am calling it.

Comment: also, how do I use await, it gives me syntax errors when I call that.

Comment: this is definitely my problem, not sure how to call this function to get this to update my state though. Or how do I call await?

Comment: i marked this correct because it was the closest solution. But mine works without the await. mapDispatchToProps was not working in my testing, and did not see the method when it was called in my component.

Comment: It's important to mark your function as `async` when you want to use `await`

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely using the exported `BookDetail` directly, instead of connected one, which is the default export. It is therefore safer to remove the `export` keyword in the `BookDetail` class declaration, so you'll get an error when you accidentally import it directly by name.

At the import site, replace `import { BookDetail } from ...` by

```
import BookDetail from ...
```

Comment: this is not the issue. I am getting a promise back, so I think it has more to do with what I am returning out of my actionCreator and how I am using it afterward. Still new to redux.

Comment: I am not getting any weback errors, so I don't think I have a mistaken import anywhere.

Comment: import BookDetail from './containers/BookDetail'; is my code where I call this

Comment: If there were no errors after removing the export, then the imports were indeed not the problem. Not entirely sure what was going on though, as it looks like you're using `redux-promise` middleware, and that should be able to handle a promise in the payload just fine.

Comment: as stated above, it as more of an issue with testing. I had shallow testing and my component was not seeing the function calls, then saying no function exists. I added a conditional and it fixed the issue.